# Invalid Date in IE with Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

All -

I know this question has came up a few times and I have made some modification, but still need help on one thing.

Originally my line of code would only work in Chrome and Firefox Not IE:

```
var tempDOH = new Date(jQuery(this).attr("ows_BirthDate"));
```

Then I did a test and formatted as such:

```
var test = new Date(2012, 11, 2, 19, 30, 0);
```

This works in all three browser.

My question is how can I write my first line of code to pull in the information in the same format as my second line does?

Much appreciated!

Comment: There's not enough information here. What does `jQuery(this).attr("ows_BirthDate")` look like?

Comment: jQuery(this).attr("ows_BirthDate") looks like: 2014-09-08 00:00:00:000

Comment: var tempDOH = new Date(jQuery(this).attr("ows_BirthDate")); looks like: Mon Sep 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)